# Where can I find videos of russian tv shows covering the russian invasion of Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, media, propaganda

I was watching a tv show in my country on the matter and they showed some footages of the russian tv shows, if I remember well one of them was called "60 minutes". The focus was on the massive propaganda people in Russia have to stand everyday.

I'm curious to watch some of these shows to see what arguments are made to justify the invasion and if there's (even a bit of) debate on what should be done.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything with a simple search on the internet.

Is there a place where I can find some of these tv shows in their integrity **with trustable subtitles in english**?

Comment: smotrim.ru has all the main shows, but no subtitles (so it seems).
People under 45 use Telegram as their main source of news regarding the military action, so you should probably go there and use some google translate.

Comment: "No debate" is the Junior Dictator Playset level. The pros create a lot of debate, but frame it as "Should we destroy Eastasia or is splitting it in two enough?" - so that the peace-leaning population roots for the second option until they identify with it.

Comment: @ZOMVID-21 interesting summary of the playset

Comment: Political shows yes, subtitles no. Sorry!

Comment: For what's worth it, RFERL has a summary of one such show (or two) https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-ukraine-war-tv-brainwashing/31776244.html

Comment: Also, I just watched a segment of news today on rutube and they still show Tucker Carlson regularly (see about 29-31 minutes in) https://rutube.ru/video/a293b4c73700deca3008d4596f3e1b1d/ In that they made an interesting "combo" linking Hunter Biden's business links with biological weapons, somehow.

Comment: China Daily obliges with a translation of the latter claims https://global.chinadaily.com.cn/a/202203/29/WS62426127a310fd2b29e53d95.html

Comment: do not forget about Telegram groups - they are not banned, of russian speakers for example Скабеева  or forces channel Силовики or use Telegram search to find it, but prepare to read on russian.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a Youtube video:

"The Big Game" Channel 1, 15/04/2022: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjjyDbfQCUY.

Extraordinary amounts of propaganda, at the end of the talk show the presenter says :

> In the modern world, we are the embodiment of the forces of good. This
> is a metaphysical clash between the forces of good and evil... This is
> truly a holy war we're waging and we must win.

Comment: The question seems to be asking for a information soruce / platform where they can find Russian propaganda (e.g. Telegram channel, TV channel, etc). In this case, a single video content may not be what the OP is looking for.