# How can Ukraine's invasion end for the Russian media and how do they justify the possible scenarios?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, media, propaganda

After writing my [first question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72265/where-can-i-find-videos-of-russian-tv-shows-covering-the-russian-invasion-of-ukr) I realized that I can ask another question so to have a good summary of the Russian positions in the media on the ways the invasion of Ukraine can end.

How does Russian media envisage the war in Ukraine will end? Is there someone who says that annexation of part of Ukraine can be a good thing, or they say that they want "just" independence of Donbass, Crimea recognition and neutrality of Ukraine, or even less than this? Is the peaceful part of the population even represented?

In my country for example media gives mainly two alternatives: Ukraine regains the territories lost (but not Crimea and Donbass) and Russia can come back home saying they defended Donbass so they are not just losers, or the Russia manages to negotiate annexation of some other part (at least in the southeast). A question arises naturally : How even Russian media justify the second scenario if they told the invasion is a special military operation? Is it even discussed? Do they just blame Zelensky not to accept their requests (not regarding new annexations)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have now read this question 4 times.  And I still don't understand what you are asking.  Please, rewrite it more clearly.

Comment: @wrod OP is asking how Russian media envisages the war in Ukraine will end.

Comment: Please, add some context. Not everyone knows what exactly you expect the readers to already know. "Alternatives", for one, are always to something, and this something is not clear from the question.

Comment: " or they just say that they want "just" independence of Donbass," AFAIK They don't want independence of Donbass. Part of Donbass was de facto independent before their intervention.

Comment: Not sure I understand the "justify" part. Why do you assume that Media in Russia (that are still operating) have to justify anything? They lie or omit part or most of the facts and just state something. Justification sounds strange in that context. Sure as hell they do not blame their own government. I think it's even illegal currently in Russia.

Comment: I edited the question to make it seem more open to discussion-though I do not know if it will even work

Answer (score 3):

I'm really not sure why you need anything else than two Putin's speeches here.

[February, 21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APPjVlUA-gs) - about the recognition of LNR and DNR.

[February, 24](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qS6J-WbTD8) - about the special military operation.

Representation in the Russian media is still in the bounds of these two speeches. Later on, there may be nuance, change of focus, etc - but if you don't have the context of those two speeches you will surely miss it when you see it.

Comment: I found the two speeches here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APPjVlUA-gs and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qS6J-WbTD8 with english subtitles, hope they are accurate translations